# How to generate a non-linear animation?

Tags: dynamic, animation

Here is a simple example, as time goes by, the speed of animation playback is increasing

[image]

The built-in function `Animate` seems to only play animation at a uniform speed, there is a related option `DefaultDuration`, I don't know how to use it correctly

[image]

What is the simple way to create this kind of animation in Mathematica?

Comment: You could make your own nonlinear function of time and use that to animate.

Comment: Instead of accelerating the `Animate` you may accelerate the expression inside `Animate`. E.g. let's call exp[i] for i=1 to 100  the expression you want to animate, then exp[i^2] for i=1 to 10 will display accelerated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to show what I meant in comments:

```
With[{tmax = 30},
 Animate[
   Graphics[
     {
       Black, Arrowheads[Large],
       Arrow[{{0, 0}, {t^3 + 10, 0}}]
     },
     PlotRange -> {{-20, tmax^3 + 10}, {-300, 300}},
     PlotRangePadding -> {Scaled[0.05], Scaled[.2]}
   ],
   {t, 1, tmax}
 ]
]
```

[image: animation]